# object not found $_GET

Tags: php, url, xampp

i'm trying to learn PHP but for some reason i am getting this weird issue (i am using XAMPP):

i have a simple code

```
<?php
echo $_GET['name'];
?>
```

and when ever i type http://localhost/lee.phpi get undefined index like i am supposed to, but when i type http://localhost/lee.php&name=lee i get an Object not found The requested URL was not found on this server error.

does anybody know why is this happening? is it my code or my pc maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 http://localhost/lee.php&name=lee
```

Is an incorrect URL altogether, it should be

```
http://localhost/lee.php?name=lee
                        ^
```

Now if you were to add a new parameter you would use an `&` only then. First one always comes after an `?`, for example

```
http://localhost/lee.php?name=lee&age=20
```

I was going to refer you to HTTP Specifications documents but since you mentioned you are learning PHP i thought that might be too overwhelming for you.

And your code is fine.

**Free Tip since you said you just started learning:**

Always read into error messages and believe in what they say while you are investigating an issue, they are there really for a purpose. For example

> The requested URL was not found on this server error.

That error message would mean that the  URL is not there on the server, if i was you i would care less about my code at that point and more about what is the reason that URL is not there when my file is there? And that would have lead me to the conclusion that the URL format is wrong.

A lot of people overlook error messages even in their advanced learning stages and say no I have  everything fine and the error message is weird, no it's not.

Comment: You're welcome. See the updated answer for a tip, it will help you on your way